# What's the difference between Digit and Acorns?

Tags: savings

[Digit](https://digit.co/) and [Acorns](https://www.acorns.com/) both seem to do similar services, what exactly are the differences between them?

Comment: Did you try reading the two sites? Acorns appears to round every purchase up to the next dollar, so if you buy something for $9.95 it moves $0.05 into your account. Digit uses a "take a few bucks a day if you can afford not to miss it".

Answer (score 1):

Acorns rounds up purchases to the nearest dollar and invests that extra change. Digit is a standard savings account but it automatically withdraws money from your checking account based on your spending patterns.